# Laravel 5.5 Update Post not working

Tags: laravel

**edit.blade.php :**

```
{!! Form::model($post, array('method'=>'PATCH','url'=>'/posts/{post}'.$post->id))  !!}

{{ method_field('PATCH') }}

{{csrf_field()}}
```

```
<label for="title">Titolo</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="{{$post->title}}">
```

```
<label for="body">Corpo</label>

<textarea id="body" name="body" class="form-control" value="{{$post->body}}">

      </textarea>
```

**routes/web.php:**

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('/posts/tags/{tag}', 'TagsController@index');
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments','CommentsController@store');
Route::get('/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
Route::get('/edit/{post}', 'PostsController@update');
Route::patch('/post/{post}', 'PostsController@update');
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
Route::get('/login', 'SessionsController@create');
Route::post('/login', 'SessionsController@store');
Route::get('/logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');
```

**postController:**

```
public function edit( Post $post )
{
    return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
}


public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    Post::where('id', $post)->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding) here, so change it to:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post){
    $post->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Also, change URL to:

```
'url' => '/posts/' . $post->id
```

Also, remove these fields, because `{!! Form::model() !!}` automatically insert those for you:

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Ok now it works .. but dont update a post just create a new post

Comment: @Matteo you haven't asked about this. Use an additional method or `updateOrCreate()` method if you also want to be able to create a new post if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I already have create a post, i just wanna be able to reedit and update a post

Comment: @Matteo but it can't create a new post. If you're using `update()` method as I've shown and the `PostsController@update` method is executed.

Comment: I know, but it create a new Post

Comment: @Matteo this can happen only if you're submitting the form to `/posts` and not to a route like `/posts/7`

Comment: so i need to add /posts/{id} ?

Comment: @Matteo if you want to update, you need to make sure that you're executing correct method and the form is submitted to `/posts/5` kind of route and not to `/posts`.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
Post::where('id', $post)->update($request->all());
```

**To:**

```
Post::where('id', $post->id)->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

**new route:**

Route::patch('/posts/{id}/edit/{post}', 'UpdateController@update');

{!! Form::model($post, array('method'=>'POST','url'=>'/posts/{id}/edit'. $post->id))  !!}

I think /posts/{id}/edit not working